# Show inactive application on top of fullscreen mode application

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion

While play youtube video in full-screen mode, is there anyway to make an inactive application still display on top of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `NSWindow`'s `setLevel:` documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html). The acceptable arguments are:

```
#define NSNormalWindowLevel          kCGNormalWindowLevel
#define NSFloatingWindowLevel        kCGFloatingWindowLevel
#define NSSubmenuWindowLevel         kCGTornOffMenuWindowLevel
#define NSTornOffMenuWindowLevel     kCGTornOffMenuWindowLevel
#define NSMainMenuWindowLevel        kCGMainMenuWindowLevel
#define NSStatusWindowLevel          kCGStatusWindowLevel
#define NSModalPanelWindowLevel      kCGModalPanelWindowLevel
#define NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel       kCGPopUpMenuWindowLevel
#define NSScreenSaverWindowLevel     kCGScreenSaverWindowLevel
#define NSDockWindowLevel            kCGDockWindowLevel
```

I tested this with `NSScreenSaverWindowLevel` and it still appeared over a fullscreen YouTube video playing in Chrome.